# Google Drive webContentLink for files that aren't public have started producing 403s

Tags: google-drive-api

Our intranet uses the Google Drive SDK to produce links to lots of documents stored on drive. I use the webContentLink property of the file which produces a link that looks like:

https://docs.google.com/a/hda.org.uk/uc?id=0B0H_jrqJX7xeWkNRM2hXd1ExMUE&export=download

For public files that still works fine to download the file but for files that only staff have access to it has started producing a "Forbidden Error 403" page. This was all working until earlier this week when the 403s started appearing. The users are logged in with their cookies set and can access the files if they go to drive but can't use webContentLink to download them any more.

Comment: And... they've magically started working again in the past hour for everyone at the company after having four days without the ability to download documents.Google's total lack of transparency and tendency to change services, which we're paying for,  without any warning, is more than a little irritating.

Comment: No, they've stopped working again and gone back to the 403 forbidden message. Incredibly annoying.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No, it works some of the time but then returns the 403 other times with no explanation, no way of getting support so we're using an individual server for files for now and looking to switch to dropbox or another file service.

Comment: Could it be a quota or rate limit issue?